# how to refresh GridView in $.ajax

Tags: asp.net, jquery

how to use grid view control in below method

```
public static string ServerSideMethod()
    {
            strSend = "File uploaded sucessfully";
           Database db = new Database();
        db.Add(name);

           GridView1.DataSource = db.LoadCourses();//showing error
    GridView1.DataBind();   //showing error
        }
        return strSend;
      }
```

my below scripts calling ServerSideMethod

```
 $.ajax(
                {
                    type: "POST",
                    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                    url: "UploadResx.aspx/ServerSideMethod",
                    data: "{ sendData: 'ok' }",
                    success: function (result) {

                        alert(result.d);

                    }
                })
```

please let me know how to refresh GridView1

Comment: one question, how you can access asp.net control (GridView1) in a static function?

Comment: yes i know we can't use but could you advice me how to refresh grid with updated record.

Comment: you can use update panel control, which will update the grid without refresh the page..if you need a code smple..let me know.. i will update on aswer

Comment: yes pls if we hide the GridView1.DataSource = db.LoadCourses();
    GridView1.DataBind();  in ServerSideMethod then how can i refresh my grid with updated record

Answer (score 0):

You can't access web controls in in a static method directly. Instead of you can use other HTML tables plugins like DataTable.

EDIT

aspx page

```
    <asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server">    </asp:ScriptManager>
    <asp:Button ID="btnsearch" runat="server" Text="SEARCH" OnClick="btnsearch_Click" />
    <asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel2" runat="server">
        <ContentTemplate>                                                                                                                                     
        <asp:GridView ID="grdjobs" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="false" DataKeyNames="Id" AllowPaging="true"  
                PageSize="10" OnPageIndexChanging="grdjobs_PageIndexChanging" GridLines="None" Width="950px" EmptyDataText="No Records Found">
            <Columns>
                <asp:BoundField DataField="jobid" HeaderText="JOB" ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center">  
                    <ItemStyle Width="50px"></ItemStyle>
                </asp:BoundField>                      
                <asp:BoundField DataField="summary" HeaderText="JOB SUMMARY" >
                    <ItemStyle Width="300px"></ItemStyle>
                </asp:BoundField>                                         
            </Columns>
                <RowStyle CssClass="RowStyle" />
                <EmptyDataRowStyle CssClass="EmptyRowStyle" />
                <PagerStyle CssClass="PagerStyle" />
                <SelectedRowStyle CssClass="SelectedRowStyle" />
                <HeaderStyle CssClass="HeaderStyle" />
                <EditRowStyle CssClass="EditRowStyle" />
                <AlternatingRowStyle CssClass="AltRowStyle" />                                    
        </asp:GridView>
        </ContentTemplate>
            <Triggers>
                <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="btnsearch" EventName="Click" /> 
            </Triggers>
        </asp:UpdatePanel>
```

code behind

```
try
        {
            grdmyjobs.DataSource = GetMyJobs(empid);  // function return dataset
            grdmyjobs.DataBind();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Response.Redirect("error.aspx?errmsg=Error: " + ex.Message);
        }
```

Comment: updated the code sample, in example, when click on search button the grid will refresh the data without refresh the page...

Answer (score 0):

I'm not exactly sure what you mean but I guess you're trying to refresh your gridview from JavaScript, right? You can use little trick.

To your aspx page put div and a button inside it:
(note: set ClientIDMode of button to static if you're using .NET 4.0+)

```
<div id="triggerDiv" style="display:none;">
  <asp:Button ID="triggerButton" runat="server" Text="" ClientIDMode="Static"...
<div>
```

In your JavaScript you can completely skip your ajax code and simply call this:

```
//if you use .NET framework 4.0+
$('#triggerButton').click();

//if not, use something like this
$('#triggerDiv > input[type="button"]').click();
```

Summary:

1. You need a button which is invisible but can cause a postback (if you use UpdatePanel put this  with button inside that UpdatePanel's content template so the postback is caused to this particular area.
2. To refresh a gridview from JavaScript simply trigger the click event of the hidden button.

Comment: where i put my grid view?

Comment: doesn't really matter. Anywhere on the APSX page. Or - if you are using the UpdatePanel then you have to put my code and GridView to the content template.